# Dev Tools Don't Show Cache-Control in Response Only no-cache (on Apache Server)

Tags: cache, apache

I have followed the tutorial to setup Browser Caching on My Droplet: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-apache-content-caching-on-ubuntu-14-04

What I want to accomplish for now is set up a year-long cache on all files but later on will fine-tune files like HTML for a much shorter expiry.

I have checked my cache folder with below and it is growing: ls -la /var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk/

But the problem is Google Page Insight and other page speed tests are still reporting that there is not cache policy applied to my files even after 2 days of caching applied to the server.

I have also check edge dev tools and most files don't show Cache-Control in response and for some a small subset of files that it is shown, it is set to no-cache.

I included the following lines in my domain's virtual host file and enabled caching on my server:

```
CacheQuickHandler off
CacheLock on
CacheLockPath /tmp/mod_cache-lock
CacheLockMaxAge 5
CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie

<Location />
    CacheEnable disk
    CacheHeader on
    CacheDefaultExpire 600
    CacheMaxExpire 86400
    CacheLastModifiedFactor 0.5

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault A31536000

    Header set Cache-Control public
    Header merge Cache-Control max-age=31536000
    FileETag All
</Location>
```

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour].

Answer (score 0):

After days of headache I finally solved it. I was editing the Virtual Host for HTTP and not the one for HTTPs/SLL. If any body faces this problem just search for active virtual host files on your server like below:

$ apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  de****.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf:2)
*:80                   de****.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)